# Some problems about python crawler

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I learned about python crawler few days ago and then did some practice. But I met a problem and I don't know how to solve it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time


def crawler(url, data=None):
    wb_data = requests.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(wb_data.text, 'lxml')
    headers = soup.select('div.pho_info > h4 > em')
    addresses = soup.select('div.pho_info > p > span.pr5')
    prices = soup.select('#pricePart > div.day_l > span')
    images1 = soup.select('#curBigImage')
    images2 = soup.select('div.member_pic > a > img')
    names = soup.select('div.w_240 > h6 > a')
    genders = soup.select('div.member_pic > div')

    def crawl_gender(a):
        if a == 'member_ico1':
            return 'man'
        elif a == 'member_ico':
            return 'woman'
    if data == None:
        for header, address, price, image1, image2, name, gender in zip(headers, addresses, prices, images1, images2, names, genders):
        data = {
            'header': header.get('header'),
            'address': address.get('adderss'),
            'price': price.get('price'),
            'image1': image1.get('image1'),
            'image2': images2.get('src'),
            'name': name.get('name'),
            'gender': crawl_gender(genders)
        }
            print(data)

 crawler('http://bj.xiaozhu.com/fangzi/1115060277.html')
```

and following is what compiler returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/duanshulan/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Crawler.py", line 36, in <module>
    crawler('http://bj.xiaozhu.com/fangzi/1115060277.html')
  File "/Users/duanshulan/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Crawler.py", line 30, in crawler
    'image2': images2.get('src'),
  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Did you mean `image2` (not `images2`)?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have more than 1 image in your `images2` variable. Try:

```
'image2': images2[0].get('src'),
```

to access the first one only.